# Manage file access rights based on 2 groups combination

Tags: groups, access-rights

I am setting up a sharepoint site where files have 2 properties (a Country and a Department). I want to create corresponding groups to manage user access rights to these files based on the combination of the 2 groups corresponding to each file.

For instance here is a list of files:

```
Name      Country      Category
-----------------------------------
File1     England      Sales
File2     England      Finance
File3     Spain        Sales
File4     Spain        Finance
File5     Spain        Logistics
File6     Italy        Sales
File7     Italy        Marketing
File8     Italy        Finance
```

Case 1. John is part of England group and Sales group, he can access File1 only

Case 2. Pedro is part of Spain group and Sales and Finance groups, he can access File3 and File4

Case 3. Marcus is a corporate finance employee, he belongs to England, Spain and Italy groups (all countries) and the Finance group, he can access File2, File4, File8

Is this possible? Can you provide details how if yes?